# PooledCloseableHttpClient impacting performance throughput

Tags: performance, ssl, spring-integration, httpclient, connection-pooling

I have been using Spring-Integration to call a REST api, however the http-client which comes by default with Spring-Integration does not support connection-pooling or reusability, so I customized to use **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager**

But now Spring-integration stopped picking up the JKS files in my classpath, so I built my own SSL Context, however building this SSL Context caused significant drop in performance

For 100 concurrent threads,

1. Using http client I got 200 TPS
2. Using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER, I got up to 380 TPS.
3. Building SSL context from JKS **buildSslContext()** I get less than 30 TPS :(

**Context.xml**

```
<int:gateway id="ServiceRequestGateway"
             service-interface="com.company.security.integration.RequestGateway"
             default-request-channel="RequestChannel"
             default-reply-channel="ResponseChannel">
    <int:default-header name="Accept" value="application/json; v=5"/>
    <int:default-header name="Content-Type" value="application/json; v=5"/>
    <int:default-header name="ServiceType" expression="#args[1]"/>
</int:gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
        id="Outbound_Gateway"
        request-channel="RequestChannel"
        reply-channel="ResponseChannel"
        request-factory="requestFactory"
        header-mapper="headerMapper"
        url="${service.host}/{xyzServiceType}"
        http-method="POST"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        extract-request-payload="true">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="ServiceType" expression="headers['xyzServiceType']" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<!--Connection Pooling/Keep Alive/Retry-->
<bean id="httpClient" class="com.capitalone.security.config.PooledCloseableHttpClient">
</bean>

<bean id="requestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="5000"/>
    <property name="readTimeout"    value="5000"/>
</bean>
```

**PooledCloseableHttpClient**

```
public class PooledCloseableHttpClient implements FactoryBean {

@Autowired
S3ClientUtil s3Client;

// For TLS/SSL connectivity from this client to service
@Value("${jks.filename}")
String jksFile;

// Password for Java keystores
@Value("${keystore.password}")
String keystorePassword;

private int maxRetries = 2;
//1 second
@Value("${rest.call.request.retryInterval:1000}")
private int retryInterval = 1000;

@Value("${rest.call.request.keepAliveTime:60}")
private int keepAliveTime = 60;

@Value("${rest.call.request.maxConnection:200}")
private int maxConnection = 200;

@Value("${rest.call.request.maxConnectionsPerRoute:100}")
private int maxConnectionsPerRoute = 100 ;

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory;

// Custom Keep-Alive
ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy = (response, context) -> {
    HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator
            (response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
        String param = he.getName();
        String value = he.getValue();
        if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase
                ("timeout")) {
            return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
        }
    }
    return keepAliveTime * 1000;
};

// Called once during initialization to get JKS file from Cloud
private SSLContext buildSslContext() {
    try {
        // Get the JKS contents and then use the pooling connection manager below
        File keyStoreFile = s3Client.importKeystoreFile(jksFile);

        // Build key store from JKS file downloaded from S3
        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile); // Get Keystore
            keyStore.load(is, keystorePassword.toCharArray()); //Get keystore password
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
        }

        // Build SSL Context
        SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder = new SSLContextBuilder();
        sslBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
        sslBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(keyStoreFile, keystorePassword.toCharArray());

        return sslBuilder.build();
    } catch (final GeneralSecurityException | IOException exc) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getObject() throws Exception {

    //Build PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
            RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
                    .register("https", new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(buildSslContext(), new NoopHostnameVerifier()))
                    .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).build());

    // Build HttpClient
    HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom().useSystemProperties().setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager)
            .setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy)
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
            .setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(new ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(maxRetries, retryInterval));
    return httpClientBuilder.build();
}

@Override
public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return CloseableHttpClient.class;
}

@Override
public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Don't you think that your problem is here `// Build key store from JKS file downloaded from S3` ? There is nothing from Spring Integration side, BTW. It just uses `RestTemplate` underneath. But more over it looks like your problem is up to Apache Commons HTTP Client.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Downloading jks file logic was always there, btw in my project I also have another `RestTemplate` defined as bean explicitly to call another service using another set of JKS. Any SSL configuration I defined in this `RestTemplate` bean is being overridden by  Spring integration `PooledCloseableHttpClient` I have above. Any idea how to keep them separate, that should solve my problems because then I can simply use `useSystemProperties ` in my `HttpClient` instead of building my own SSL Context. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the refactored HttpClient class which gave me the optimum performance.

```
public class PooledCloseableHttpClient implements FactoryBean {

@Autowired
S3ClientUtil s3Client;

// For TLS/SSL connectivity from this client to service
@Value("${jks.filename}")
String jksFile;

// Password for Java keystores
@Value("${keystore.password}")
String keystorePassword;

private int maxRetries = 2;
//1 second
@Value("${rest.call.request.retryInterval:1000}")
private int retryInterval = 1000;

@Value("${rest.call.request.keepAliveTime:60}")
private int keepAliveTime = 60;

@Value("${rest.call.request.maxConnection:200}")
private int maxConnection = 200;

@Value("${rest.call.request.maxConnectionsPerRoute:100}")
private int maxConnectionsPerRoute = 100 ;

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory;

// Custom Keep-Alive
ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy = (response, context) -> {
    HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator
            (response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
        String param = he.getName();
        String value = he.getValue();
        if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase
                ("timeout")) {
            return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
        }
    }
    return keepAliveTime * 1000;
};

// Called once during initialization to get JKS file from Cloud
private SSLContext buildSslContext() {
    try {
        // Get the JKS contents and then use the pooling connection manager below
        File keyStoreFile = s3Client.importKeystoreFile(jksFile);

        // Build key store from JKS file downloaded from S3
        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile); // Get Keystore
            keyStore.load(is, keystorePassword.toCharArray()); //Get keystore password
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
        }

        // Build SSL Context
        SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder = new SSLContextBuilder();
        sslBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
        sslBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(keyStoreFile, keystorePassword.toCharArray());

        return sslBuilder.build();
    } catch (final GeneralSecurityException | IOException exc) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getObject() throws Exception {

    //Build PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
            RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
                    .register("https", new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(buildSslContext(), new NoopHostnameVerifier()))
                    .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).build())
        poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxConnection);
        poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnectionsPerRoute);

    // Build HttpClient
    HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom().useSystemProperties().setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager)
                .setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy)
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                .setConnectionReuseStrategy((arg0, arg1) -> true)
                .setMaxConnTotal(maxConnection)
                .setMaxConnPerRoute(maxConnectionsPerRoute)
                .setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(new ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(maxRetries, retryInterval));
    return httpClientBuilder.build();
}

@Override
public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return CloseableHttpClient.class;
}

@Override
public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
}
}
```